# Spatial Mapping Renderer Bug (HoloLens)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am asking myself if I don't understand the spatial mapping concept fully or if there is a bug in Unity (**Unity HoloLens 5.4.0b24-HTP (64-bit)**) concerning the **Spatial Mapping Renderer**.

I added it to the main camera and in the emulator (10.0.14342.1018) I can see wireframes thus it is at least working somehow but it always felt "a little bit wrong" just like there is some kind of clipping bug.

In the following picture one can see that a wireframe gets rendered

[image: Wireframe available]

but if I look at the couch nothing gets rendered. But there should be something, right?

[image: but not always]

Update: Camera Setup Being Used
[image: Camera Setup Being Used]

Is there someone out there who can enlighten me? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the camera near/far clip plane values? It works fine for me so I doubt there is a bug.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the camera properties. I still have the default values 0.3 and 1000.

Comment: Isn't your camera inside a hologram?

Comment: No, I just have that little hologram from the tutorial and in this example this hologram is far away from the current camera position and also in the hierarchy, the camera is not a child of something and I can move around quite a lot without seeing anything. And you are also using the most recent version? Thanks for your help and ideas!

Comment: I guess we have the latest of it all. Are you sure your computer and GPU are up to the requirements? Have you ever got it working or is it a first? If you remove the spatial mapping, do you get it running fine? And final question, if you try to move an item on the wireframe, does it move along fine? (pfiouuuu so many questions...)

Comment: Currently testing on a Surface Pro 4. I think the GPU is good enough. I got it once working with an older beta not using the Spatial Mapping Renderer but the SpatialMapping.cs from the Microsoft tutorial. But with the latest beta only trouble. ;) Currently my test project is more or less empty. I wanted to start with visualizing the surrounding now I even removed the one hologram. :) That is the reason why I currently cannot move things around that easily...